# Optimize RAM Android ImageView

Tags: android

I'm creating game quest, logic based on loading drawable from res/drawable into imageView by clicking some image.
All background image is HD resolution. Always I have png frame in HD - 3.8kb. All of background pictures is jpg and weight between 120 and 250kb.
So, I'm useing
    camera.setImageResource(R.drawable.cam1);

After splash, main menu, select episode and other steps in different activities I got over 100mb ram in use. So, it works good on my Z1 Compact , but on others
 budgete cellphones work slowly and outofmemory.

How can I use drawable optimally in my game?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just need to use OpenGL to load image in video memory, but not into RAM.  This can save for us a lot of free memory